# Why don't the cables from the power supply (CPU1-P4 and CPU2-P8) to the motherboard (ATX_12v_2x2 and ATX_12v_2x4) fit?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, power

Putting together the first PC. I can't figure out how to connect the processor (intel Core i7 10700) from the power supply ([be quiet! Pure Power 11 700W](https://www.bequiet.com/en/powersupply/1534)) on the [Gigabyte Z490 AORUS ELITE AC](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z490-AORUS-ELITE-AC-rev-10/sp#sp) motherboard.

From the power supply, there are two connectors CPU1-P4 and CPU2-P8 (Photo 1, Photo 2). As I understand it, they need to be inserted into the ATX_12v_2x2 / ATX_12v_2x4 connectors on the motherboard (photo 3).

The fact is that the connectors themselves do not fit in my opinion. If you look at Photo 3 and Photo 4, you can see that which connectors have the shape of a square, and some with slices. But the connectors from the power supply (Photo 1 and Photo 2) have a different order of connector shapes.

I don't understand what to do ...

1. Combine CPU1-P4 and CPU2-P8 and insert into the connector on the right, consisting of eight connectors (Photo 3) and do not pay attention that the shapes do not fit?
2. Insert CPU1-P4 or CPU2-P8 into the left connector where there are 4 connectors, and CPU1-P4 or CPU2-P8 into the right one where there are 8 connectors.
3. Or is the power supply not suitable?

Please tell me what the problem is.

> [image: Photo 1]

> [image: Photo 2]

> [image: Photo 3]

> [image: Photo 4]

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is this:

Combine both connectors CPU1 and CPU2 (photo 2)

and plug them into ATX_12V_2X4 (photo 3 first from right to left)

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rucfmsGjPow) on Youtube on how to plug them properly on min 3:20